# Missing New Interface Library Wizard

Tags: redhawksdr

I would like to add a new Interface Library, according to recent redhawk 2.0.1 documentaion (entry 14.5.5) there should be "New Interface Library Wizard", but I could not find it. Any tips?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the REDHAWK IDL Project

file -> new -> REDHAWK IDL Project

Or

file -> new -> other

And then find it in that list.

`Ctrl + n` is the hotkey to bring up the new project wizard

Answer (score 0):

)There is also a New Java Interface (File->New->Other->Java->Interface).  But the section of the manual you cite it talking about the REDHAWK IDL Project as previously stated.